# I have a Laravel and JavaScript project, but the 'play' button doesn't work on initial page load; I need to reload it every time to use it again

Tags: javascript, html, laravel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HALI.png)
Upon entering the page, users should have instant access to listen to my music
I have added a page to my portfolio dedicated to music, where anyone can access it and listen to the tracks they want. When a user enters the page, they have the opportunity to listen to these tracks. The reason for my question is why do I have to reload the page every time to press play.
I have noticed that all algorithms written with JavaScript have this issue with Blade

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Post it as text, instead.

Comment: I noticed you have a loop that creates buttons and that they all have the same id.

Comment: Thank you James, but the issue applies to all scripts, not just the button!

Comment: It seems that there is something blocking the loading of the DOM